# Test speed of two scripts

Tags: python, performance, bash, testing

I'd like to test the speed of a bash script and a Python script. How would I get the time it took to run them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're on Linux (or another UN*X), try [`time`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?time):

> The  time  command  runs   the  specified program command with the given
>          arguments.  When command finishes, time writes a  message  to  standard
>          error  giving  timing statistics about this program run.  These statis-
>          tics consist of (i) the elapsed real time between invocation and termi-
>          nation, (ii) the user CPU time (the sum of the tms_utime and tms_cutime
>          values in a struct tms as returned by times(2)), and (iii)  the  system
>          CPU  time  (the  sum of the tms_stime and tms_cstime values in a struct
>          tms as returned by times(2)).

Note that you need to eliminate outer effects - e.g. other processes using the same resources can skew the measurement.

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you can use

```
time ./script.sh
time python script.py
```

Answer (score 0):

At the beginning of each script output the start time and at the end of each script output the end time.  Subtract the times and compare.  Or use the time command if it is available as others have answered.